# Display only content from one category in two rows / columns

Tags: php, wordpress

How do you get only certain entries to show from one category I want to have two columns with two sets of entries both from different categories, I'm also trying to get one to show 10 posts the other 5 any idea's?.

Here is my current code :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="art-av">
<div id="av-side-l">
<div id="av"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { /* loades the post's featured thumbnail, requires Wordpress 3.0+ */ echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</div>'; } ?>
</div>
<div id="date-av"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></div>
<div id="com-av"><?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></div>
</div>
<div id="av-side-r">
<div id="tit-av"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="blue" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<div id="dec-av">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: can you give us some more information, also clean up your punctuation and grammar.  not sure exactly what you're looking for here

Comment: What did you try? Frankly, from what I see here, you haven't tried anything to get "two sets of entries"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => [5 or 10],
    'category' => [name, slug, whatever]
);

$posts = get_posts()
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    // the rest of your code here
}
```